# How to import and export files in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, node-modules

https://hastebin.com/ipuyupuqop.js main JS file

https://hastebin.com/meninifuku.js JS file with issues

I've been working on an API, however, routing doesn't seem to work. I've overcome some issues with this, however, this is the issue that is most affecting me.

```
C:\Users\-----\WebstormProjects\BoR-CORE\routes\v1\account.js:3
let router = express.Router();
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'Router' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\-----\WebstormProjects\BoR-CORE\routes\v1\account.js:3:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\-----\WebstormProjects\BoR-CORE\app.js:17:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
```

Comment: I think the last line in `main.js` should be `module.exports = {express}`

Comment: I fount one copy past example here https://wiki.workassis.com/node-js-export-and-import/ may be this will help you

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are exporting wrong file. You need to export router and import this into `app.js`.

This should be like this:

```
//File router/index.js
const user         = require('./user'),
      error        = require('./error'),
      response     = require('./response');

module.exports = function(app) {

    app.get('/v1/details', user.checkUser, user.getDetails, response.sendResponse);

    app.post('/v1/details', user.checkUser, user.insertDetails, response.sendResponse);

};



//Your `app.js`

"use strict";
//NPM Modules
const express           = require('express'),
      path              = require('path'),
      cookieParser      = require('cookie-parser'),
      bodyParser        = require('body-parser'),
      //Internal Modules
      router            = require('./router');

var app = express();

// configure the app to use bodyParser()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

console.log('server listening at 127.0.0.1 over port 2318'.info);

app.use(cookieParser());
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

router(app);

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should export the router like `module.exports = router;`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your second file.

Instead of requiring the main app to get the express object, simply require('express') itself.

I think it should work this way.